# Make sure that randomly assigned attribute is not duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I have this scenario. There are six differently positioned placeholders on the page. I have six different words, and each word should be randomly assigned to one placeholder.

What I want to achieve is that there are no duplicated words, e.g. placeholder nr.3 gets "Word-1" and placeholder nr.6 gets "Word-1".

This is the JavaScript that I am using to randomly assign words to placeholders, in my case paragraph elements.

```
var word_1 = $('#main').append('<p class="word word-1"></p>'),
word_2 = $('#main').append('<p class="word word-2"></p>'),
word_3 = $('#main').append('<p class="word word-3"></p>'),
word_4 = $('#main').append('<p class="word word-4"></p>'),
word_5 = $('#main').append('<p class="word word-5"></p>'),
word_6 = $('#main').append('<p class="word word-6"></p>');

var pos_1 = $('.word-1').css({'left' : '0', 'right' : '0', 'top' : '48%'})
var pos_2 = $('.word-2').css({'left' : '-400px', 'right' : '0', 'top' : '58%'})
var pos_3 = $('.word-3').css({'left' : '0', 'right' : '-400px', 'top' : '36%'})
var pos_4 = $('.word-4').css({'left' : '0', 'right' : '-320px', 'top' : '61%'})
var pos_5 = $('.word-5').css({'left' : '-500px', 'right' : '0', 'top' : '36%'})
var pos_8 = $('.word-6').css({'left' : '-320px', 'right' : '0', 'top' : '46%'})

var words = ['word-1', 'word-2', 'word-3', 'word-4', 'word-5', 'word-6'];

$('.word').each(function(){
classIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
$(this).text(words[classIndex]);
})
```

Here is a fiddle that illustrates what I want to achieve.
http://jsfiddle.net/somkchza/

Comment: why not: set up an array of the 6 words you want, shuffle the array (so they're now assigned randomly), then assign from that to each of the positions.

Comment: @TarynEast How that differs from what I am already doing? Please bear in mind that I am a JS novice.

Comment: Ah no I see the difference. Right now you are doing random 6 times... which means you might get the same word again... if you make the array once - and then randomise the order... you will guarantee that each word is only once.

Comment: @madebym shuffle != random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add: ***words.splice(classIndex,1);***  inside the loop to remove the word used:

```
$('.word').each(function(){
    classIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    $(this).text(words[classIndex]);
    words.splice(classIndex,1);
})
```

Comment: Great, so simple, yet effective !!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to shuffle the array and then assign each one to the word.

The way you're doing it now, you will randomly pick out a word and you might get the same word twice. You don't need that.

If you shuffle the array - you've got each word only once, but shuffle it to get the random order. Then assign each one to your `.word` spot

I am not bugfixing this, or writing your shuffle algorithm for you but try something like:

```
var words = ['word-1', 'word-2', 'word-3', 'word-4', 'word-5', 'word-6'];

# google how to shuffle an array and put that function somewhere
# eg https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/shuffle-array/
words = Shuffle(words);

# they are already random - so now just assign each one to a place
$('.word').each(function(){
   $(this).text(words[classIndex]);
})
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but couldn't get it working. Seems there is a more elegant solution to this with `splice`

Comment: Note: i told you I didn't bugfix it.
splice is another solution... but it's not the most elegant. You shouldn't need to cut a word out each time, just loop through them and assign them one at a time to the thing you need